# Form Based Authentication with Active Directory

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, active-directory, forms-authentication

I have seen many implementations which uses FBA using SQL, but I am not able to find any examples on implementing FBA with Active Directory.

I need to implement FBA with Active Directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed following article for a number of times to implement FBA but never had a luck
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ee806890.aspx

After doing alot of research I found the actual problem that I was using SharePoint Foundation 2013. It does not has the implementation of LDAP classes. The logic is stripped out from these classes in SP Foundation 2013.

I installed SP Server 2013 Enterprise and followed same steps again and everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this nice blog which explains in detail the steps involved. This involves configuring Ldap membership.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/nishants/archive/2009/05/22/how-to-configure-forms-based-authentication-active-directory-ldapmembership.aspx

- Step 1: Extend SharePoint web application
- Step 2: Make entries in web.config (this is Ldap membership configuration)
- Step 3: Configure Forms authentication in central admin

Make sure AllowAnonymous is set to enabled on the SharePoint web application, so that users can access the login page.

In `Web.Config` we have to add a provider which points to Ldap membership provider. Along with this we have to configure RoleManager with `defaultProvider` as `AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider`

After this, we have to configure the provider in Central Admin and choose forms authentication

Comment: Please do not post link-only-answers. Instead try to include the relevant portions of the post in your answer, using the link merly as a source

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but receiving a -1 makes everyone feel that an answer is irrelevant. For new users, try giving the suggestions as comments than demotivating them. (My intention was not to promote the mentioned blog, but to point the right answer)

Comment: @Sriram Will it work with SharePoint Foundation 2013?

Comment: I don't think you need anonymous enabled. The folders that have the login pages have web.config files that allow all users to access them.

Comment: Hey, I'm resurrecting the dead here, but a REALLY important reason why Robert's comment is important is that the blog is gone. Thanks for leaving details! /s